# Passing Variable across iFrames ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, iframe, coldfusion

I am trying to understand what another developer was doing when they tried to pass a variable from one iframe to another iframe using javascript and coldfusion.

**What is happening:** Instead of showing the image in the bottom frame that image is a forced download. And the first part of the if statement is showing as if CurrentImage was = "".

**What should happen:** The value of CurrentImage found in the URL should be passed to the bottom iFrame and that variable would be an image name which would show that image in the bottom window.

HTML Main Page

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="120,407*" FRAMEBORDER="YES" BORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" COLS="*"> 
    <FRAME NAME="selectFrame" SCROLLING="NO" SRC="selectframe.cfm">
    <FRAME ONFOCUS="selectFrame.reassignFocus();" NAME="imageFrame" SRC="imageframe.cfm">
</FRAMESET>
```

Found in selectframe.cfm:

```
<HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>Link Fax Image</TITLE>

            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            <!--
            <CFIF SubAction IS "ImageLinked" OR SubAction IS "" OR SubAction IS "ErrNoImages" OR SubAction IS "ErrImageDeleted" OR SubAction IS "NoOverwrite">
            parent.imageFrame.location.href="imageframe.cfm?CurrentImage=<CFOUTPUT>#CurrentImage#</CFOUTPUT>";

            </CFIF>
//-->
            </SCRIPT>
```

imageframe.cfm code:

```
 <CFPARAM NAME="CurrentImage" DEFAULT=""> 

<!--- If CurrentImage is blank, display the following message --->
<CFIF #CurrentImage# IS "">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>No images to link at this time.</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <CENTER><H2>No images to link at this time.</H2></CENTER>
    <CENTER><A HREF="/admin/imagelink/" TARGET="_parent">Refresh Page</A></CENTER>
</HTML>

<CFELSE>
<h3>Yes there is a Current Image</h3>
    <CFIF #CurrentImage# NEQ "NULL">
        <CFIF FileExists("#FaxImageTempDir##CurrentImage#")>
            <CFIF CurrentImage CONTAINS ".PDF">
                <CFCONTENT TYPE="application/pdf" FILE="#FaxImageTempDir##CurrentImage#" DELETEFILE="No">
            <CFELSE>
                <CFCONTENT TYPE="image/tiff" FILE="#FaxImageTempDir##CurrentImage#" DELETEFILE="No">
            </CFIF>
        <CFELSE>
        File not found, please contact support.
        </CFIF>
    </CFIF>
</CFIF>
```

Comment: `CFCONTENT` is forcing the browser to download the image, this is probably because tif is not a widely supported image format in browsers. If you want to display the image inline you'll need to convert it to a png or jpg format. If you already have it in a supported format, just add a conditional check of the file extension and if it's a tiff, download else show it inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and forgot something so simple.

Wrap the Frameset in CFOUTPUT

So if you go to page: page.cfm?var=ABC123

```
      <cfoutput>

      <FRAMESET ROWS="120,407*" FRAMEBORDER="YES" BORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" COLS="*"> 
      <FRAME NAME="selectFrame" SCROLLING="NO" SRC="selectframe.cfm?var=#var#">
      <FRAME ONFOCUS="selectFrame.reassignFocus();" NAME="imageFrame" SRC="imageframe.cfm">
      </FRAMESET>

      </cfoutput>
```

ABC123 will pass into the Framesets.

Below is an example of setting up a TV Message Board through a RaspberryPi.
I can create multiple message boards using this same code.

```
      <HTML>

      <cfoutput>

      <frameset rows="0%,15%,69%,16%" framespacing="0">

      <frame src="force.cfm?said=#said#" name="force" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">

      <frame src="pit.cfm?said=#said#" name="pit" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no">

      <frameset cols="65%,35%" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" framespacing="0">

      <FRAME src="_schedule.cfm?said=#said#" name="sch" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
      <FRAME src="_advert.cfm?said=#said#" name="banner" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">

      </frameset>

      <frame src="pib.cfm?said=#said#" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="bot">

      </frameset>
      </cfoutput>
      </HTML>
```